# brew gives: "Error: gocryptfs has been disabled because it requires FUSE!" during encfsgui installation

Tags: homebrew

I'm receiving errors while installing [pyencfsgui](https://github.com/corelan/pyencfsgui)

When I run `brew install encfs` or `brew install encfs` I get the message `Error: encfs / gocryptfs has been disabled because it requires FUSE!`

I've installed the osxfuse brew package and rebooted my mac.

After receiving the error message above, I installed the macfuse desktop package and rebooted my mac again.

[image]

output of `brew config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.1.2-11-gf904d63
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: f904d63e04b771d9ea2f42dd0523f9bb3f5bb814
Last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 4815f82c119f8f46847f8ddbc6264e02e1a67925
Core tap last commit: 40 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.DEMpKIGHTF/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.31.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.13.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
Xcode: 10.1
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

output of `brew list`

```
==> Formulae
adwaita-icon-theme      libatomic_ops           ocaml
ant             libbluray           openblas
aom             libcroco            opencore-amr
aria2               libepoxy            openjdk
atk             libev               openjpeg
autoconf            libevent            openssl@1.1
autoconf-archive        libffi              opus
automake            libgphoto2          p11-kit
bchunk              libicns             p7zip
bdw-gc              libiconv            pango
bison               libid3tag           pcre
boost               libidn2             pcre2
c-ares              libimobiledevice        pidof
cairo               libmikmod           pixman
cmake               libmp3splt          pkg-config
coreutils           libmpc              portmidi
cpulimit            libogg              python
cython              libpcap             python3
docbook             libplist            python@3.8
docbook-xsl         libpng              python@3.9
doxygen             libpsl              readline
encfs               libpthread-stubs        rtmpdump
ffmpeg              librsvg             rubberband
findutils           libsamplerate           ruby
flac                libsndfile          rust
fontconfig          libsoup             sane-backends
freetype            libsoxr             scrcpy
frei0r              libssh2             sdl
fribidi             libtasn1            sdl2
gcc             libtiff             sdl_image
gd              libtool             sdl_mixer
gdbm                libunistring            sdl_net
gdk-pixbuf          libusb              sdl_ttf
gettext             libusb-compat           shared-mime-info
giflib              libusbmuxd          smpeg
git             libuv               snappy
glib                libvorbis           speex
glib-networking         libvpx              sphinx-doc
gmp             libx11              sqlite
gnome-icon-theme        libxau              ssh-copy-id
gnu-getopt          libxcb              tcl-tk
gnu-sed             libxdmcp            tesseract
gnutls              libxext             texi2html
gobject-introspection       libxml2             theora
graphite2           libxrender          unbound
grsync              libyaml             unison
gsettings-desktop-schemas   little-cms2         usbmuxd
gtk+                lzo             util-macros
gtk+3               m4              vala
guile               mad             webp
hardlink-osx            makedepend          wget
harfbuzz            mercurial           wine
hicolor-icon-theme      meson               x264
icu4c               mp3splt             x265
intltool            mpdecimal           xcb-proto
isl             mpfr                xmlto
itstool             mtr             xorgproto
jasper              nasm                xtrans
jemalloc            net-snmp            xvid
jpeg                nettle              xz
lame                nghttp2             yasm
leptonica           ninja
libass              numpy

==> Casks
android-platform-tools  macfuse         retroshare
eloston-chromium    osxfuse         spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding gocryptfs (and similarly other packages):

1. Install MacFUSE
2. Get the [latest formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gocryptfs.rb) and modify it by removing the section with Linux dependencies

```ruby
depends_on "libfuse"
depends_on :linux # on macOS, requires closed-source macFUSE
```

to get something like:

```ruby
class Gocryptfs < Formula
  desc "Encrypted overlay filesystem written in Go"
  homepage "https://nuetzlich.net/gocryptfs/"
  url "https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/releases/download/v2.4.0/gocryptfs_v2.4.0_src-deps.tar.gz"
  sha256 "45158daf20df7f94e0c9ec57ba07af21df2e25e15b8584bf3c7de96adbbc2efd"
  license "MIT"

  bottle do
    sha256 cellar: :any_skip_relocation, x86_64_linux: "dda3ad1b778225c58589831ecb20d95906e1f731c794c5982734ee19bcc3b68b"
  end

  depends_on "go" => :build
  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
  depends_on "openssl@3"

  def install
    system "./build.bash"
    bin.install "gocryptfs", "gocryptfs-xray/gocryptfs-xray"
    man1.install "Documentation/gocryptfs.1", "Documentation/gocryptfs-xray.1"
  end

  test do
    (testpath/"encdir").mkpath
    pipe_output("#{bin}/gocryptfs -init #{testpath}/encdir", "password", 0)
    assert_predicate testpath/"encdir/gocryptfs.conf", :exist?
  end
end
```

3. Install using `brew install ./gocryptfs.rb` (note the `./` part) from the directory where you saved `gocryptfs.rb`